# Splitting a dataset into two datasets in R (for ggplot2 channeled through Shiny)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I saw some similar questions here, but none exactly like mine - or if they were the same, I didn't recognize it, as a rank newbie to programming in R (I've programmed in lots of other languages, but not R!)

I have an input dataset from a csv file, that I convert with read.csv.  The dataset may or may not, have two groups in it.  I found I could split the groups as follows:

```
datalist <- split(mydata, mydata$group)
```

but then the list I get back does not play nice with ggplot2 (I get an error that it cannot plot a list variable - although the list variable, if I print it to the console, shows the split data subset?).   OK, fine.  But if I then do

```
data = as.data.frame(datalist[1])
```

And feed that to ggplot2, as.data.frame mangles my column names, and so I lose the name of the variable I want to plot.  Augh!

What I ideally want, is to split my input data as read by read.csv, into two separate variables (data frames, I take it?) that ggplot2 can recognize as valid data sets.  Actually, I want to overlay them as histograms on the same plot.

There HAS to be an easy way to do this, but I'm not gettin' it?  Advice or pointers welcome.

Comment: You can extract individual data frames by doing datalist[[index]], note the double brackets

Comment: I get an error trying that; (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' -- odd.  here is the call,    p <- qplot(value, data = datalist[[1]], colour = "cyan")

Comment: If you want to use them on the same plot, then you probably want to keep them as one data.frame. We can help with that if you show us what your data looks like (using `dput` is best to post data) and describe the plot you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a single index value then using subset might be easier (at least for interactive use.)

```
  p <- qplot(value,     # assuming there is a column named "value"
             data = subset(mydata, group==mydata$group[1]), 
             colour = "cyan")
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `split(mydata, mydata$group)` is a `list` of `data.frame`s. There is a difference in the `[` and `[[` notation: `[` subsets the list where `[[` extracts from the list. So `datalist[1]` is a list of length 1 consisting of just the first `data.frame`. `datalist[[1]]` is the `data.frame` which is in the first position. Since `ggplot` (and `qplot`) expects a `data.frame`, you need the second (double bracket) version as @Alex mentioned in the comment. I don't know why you got the error you saw and can't diagnosis it without a complete example. Using a different data set (`mtcars`), I don't see it.

```
datalist <- split(mtcars, mtcars$am)

ggplot(datalist[[1]], aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
qplot(wt, data=datalist[[1]], colour="cyan")
```

[image]

(I'm guessing you wanted `colour=I("cyan")`, but that's an unrelated issue.)

The difference in the subsetting/extraction operators can be seen here:

```
> str(datalist)
List of 2
 $ 0:'data.frame':      19 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:19] 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:19] 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:19] 258 360 225 360 147 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:19] 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 123 180 180 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:19] 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 3.92 3.07 3.07 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:19] 3.21 3.44 3.46 3.57 3.19 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:19] 19.4 17 20.2 15.8 20 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:19] 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:19] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:19] 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:19] 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 4 3 3 ...
 $ 1:'data.frame':      13 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:13] 21 21 22.8 32.4 30.4 33.9 27.3 26 30.4 15.8 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:13] 6 6 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 8 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:13] 160 160 108 78.7 75.7 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:13] 110 110 93 66 52 65 66 91 113 264 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:13] 3.9 3.9 3.85 4.08 4.93 4.22 4.08 4.43 3.77 4.22 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:13] 2.62 2.88 2.32 2.2 1.61 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:13] 16.5 17 18.6 19.5 18.5 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:13] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:13] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:13] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:13] 4 4 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 4 ...
> str(datalist[1])
List of 1
 $ 0:'data.frame':      19 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:19] 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:19] 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:19] 258 360 225 360 147 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:19] 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 123 180 180 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:19] 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 3.92 3.07 3.07 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:19] 3.21 3.44 3.46 3.57 3.19 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:19] 19.4 17 20.2 15.8 20 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:19] 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:19] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:19] 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:19] 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 4 3 3 ...
> str(datalist[[1]])
'data.frame':   19 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 ...
 $ disp: num  258 360 225 360 147 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 175 105 245 62 95 123 123 180 180 ...
 $ drat: num  3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 3.92 3.07 3.07 ...
 $ wt  : num  3.21 3.44 3.46 3.57 3.19 ...
 $ qsec: num  19.4 17 20.2 15.8 20 ...
 $ vs  : num  1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ am  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 ...
 $ carb: num  1 2 1 4 2 2 4 4 3 3 ...
```

Comment: hanks for the explanation, Brian.  The error I was getting yesterday was of another source.